# Copy file to several dynamic paths using gulp

Tags: javascript, json, gulp

I have the following gulp task. The goal is to copy each html file to more than one directory, based on a json array (`directoryData`).

```
gulp.task("reorg", () => {
  return gulp.src('./dist/**/*.html')
    .pipe(rename(function (path) {
      let fileName = path.dirname.split('/')[0];
      let directoryName = directoryData[fileName][0];
      path.dirname = `${directoryName}/${path.dirname}`;
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});
```

Currently this task will only copy each file to their first directory in the json array. I'd like to iterate over `directoryData[fileName]` and copy the file to every directory listed.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a variable that contains the destination folder, and then I would insert the variable in the `.pipe(dest([var1,var2]))`.

example:

```
var1 = './dist/';
var2 = './assets/';
```